# How to run a command with a different working directory?

Tags: shell, pwd

I use this shell pipeline to get a SQL dump using the terminal:

```
$ cd var/lib/mysql && mysqldump -uroot -p"craft" --add-drop-table craft > ~/../docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/base.sql && cd ~/..
```

As can be seen, I entered the `var/lib/mysql` directory and create the dump to a file and come back from where I was initially.

The command is correct, but, I guess it can be written concisely like without entering directly the `var/lib/mysql` directory.

Can anyone suggest that?

Comment: More generally `( cd some_place && do_stuff )` Note the parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, I don't see a reason for the two calls to `cd` at all.

You don't seem to use the directory that you `cd` into for anything. You give an absolute path for the location of the database dump.  If any custom MySQL configuration file is needed, that would be picked up from the user's home directory in any case.

You could therefore, quite likely, just use

```
mysqldump -uroot -p"craft" --add-drop-table craft \
    > ~/../docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/base.sql
```

regardless of what directory you run that from.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is not correct that I need to enter the `var/lib/mysql` to run the command for the dump.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't need to change working directory at all (as answered by Kusalananda).  However, if you're dealing with commands that *do* need a particular working directory, then there are a couple of things to know that will make it easier for you.

Firstly, since `cd` sets the `OLDPWD` variable, we can use that to return to the original directory, without having to know its name.  Secondly, we probably want to return whether or not the command succeeded, so use `;` rather than `&&` there:

```
cd "$workdir" && somecommand ; cd "$OLDPWD"
```

That's still unreliable if the first `cd` fails; to be more robust, we really need

```
if cd "$workdir" ; then somecommand ; cd "$OLDPWD" ; fi
```

Even at this point, we're struggling if we need the exit status of `somecommand` after this.

---

It's usually best to run the command in a subshell, and change only the subshell's working directory:

```
( cd "$workdir" && somecommand )
```

This last approach is what I normally use and recommend, unless you're doing something which isn't possible from a subshell, such as setting variables for subsequent commands.

Comment: `cd -` is even more portable than `cd "$OLDPWD"`

Comment: The last approach is also what I normally use.

Comment: @Stéphane, with the caveat that it also (in POSIX, at least) also prints the new working directory, so consider sending its output to `/dev/null`.